# combine a URL with json value

Tags: javascript, json, redmine

I want to add end point to an url which would be dynamic.Something like below. But following doesn't work. can someone guide me on this.

```
(href='http://localhost/redmine/projects/' + value.id)
```

Complete code is as below.

```js
$.ajax({
      dataType: "json",
      url: "http://localhost/redmine/projects.json",
      //data: $.parseJSON(data),
      success: function(results){
          
           
            $.each(results.projects, function(i,value) {
              $('.well').append('<h4 class="h5class"><a href="http://localhost/redmine/projects/'+ value.id+'">'+ value.name+'</a>: '+ '<span class="emtext">' +'('+ value.created_on + ')' +'</span>'+ '</h4>'
               + '<p class="hmpclass">'+ value.summary+ '('+ value.description + ')' +'</p>'
                + '<hr class="hrclass">'
                
                ); 
            });

           

        }
    });
```

Comment: are you doing a json ajax call or a jsonp call? Have you checked the value contained in the variable results.projects?

Comment: its a json ajax call.  not jsonp, my mistake.

Comment: can you add some line of your json?

Comment: {"project":{"id":5,"name":"This is project name","identifier":"this-is-project-name","description":"This is description","homepage":"","status":1,"is_public":true,"custom_fields":[{"id":4,"name":"Start_date"},{"id":5,"name":"End_date"},{"id":7,"name":"Stack"}],"created_on":"2015-12-05T07:40:17Z","updated_on":"2015-12-05T07:40:17Z"}}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an error here: `...ojects/'+ value.id'">'+ valu...`.

It should be: `...ojects/' + value.id + '">'+ valu...`.